# Как сохранять данные при перезагрузке сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

столкнулся с такой проблемой что не получается сохранять кол-во кликов при перезагрузке страницы, все методы по сохранению перебровал. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать сохранение, код снизу. Если что я пытаюсь сохранить количество кликов

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>кликер</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="h1">Кликов у тебя:</h1>
    <button id="buttonclick"><h1>Добывать</h1></button>
    <script src="index.js">

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
var h1Id=document.getElementById('h1');
var buttonId=document.getElementById('buttonclick');
var counter=0;
buttonId.addEventListener('click', function(){
    counter++;
    h1Id.textContent='Кликов у тебя: '+counter;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте localStorage:

```
var h1Id=document.getElementById('h1');
var buttonId=document.getElementById('buttonclick');
var counter=localStorage.getItem('counter') ?? 0;
h1Id.textContent = 'Кликов у тебя: ' + counter;

buttonId.addEventListener('click', function(){
    counter++;
    h1Id.textContent='Кликов у тебя: '+counter;
    localStorage.setItem('counter', counter);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!